# Request token with postman

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, oauth-2.0, postman

I'm trying to configure Postman to " Get New Access Token" function in order to retrieve a token before calling a resource. I'm using FOSOAuthServerBundle

this is my security.yml

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username        
    firewalls:

        oauth_token:                                   # Everyone can access the access token URL.
            pattern: ^/oauth/v2/token
            security: false

        api:
            pattern: ^/                                # All URLs are protected
            fos_oauth: true                            # OAuth2 protected resource
            stateless: true                            # Do no set session cookies
            anonymous: false                           # Anonymous access is not allowed
```

In the window where i put the authentication information I saw this line

> Callback URL
>   https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback
>   Set this as the callback URL in your app settings page.

theese are the authentication informations:

```
Auth URL: https://{{url}}/api/web/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/auth
Access Token URL: https://{{url}}/api/web/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/token
Client ID: {{client_id}}
Client Secret: {{client_secret}}
Grant Type: Client Credentials
```

where {{url}}, {{client_id}} and {{client_secret}} are Postman's environment variables.

[New Access Token page example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN6fG.png)

Where I'm wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Callback URL https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback Set this as
>   the callback URL in your app settings page.

This message has nothing to do with your access token retrieval. Once you entered all the authentication info, were you able to get the access token when you click Request Token button? If not what was the error message

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. The message I've received is

`Error getting access token from client_credentials flow. Could not send request.`

Comment: I see that there was a spelling mistake in yout token url `topken` make sure all the values are entered properly without any mistakes.

Comment: Thanks.No it' only a typo in the body of the answer. I'll fix soon.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late answer.The message I've received is

`Error getting access token from client_credentials flow. Could not send request`.

[This is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iPB0.png)